# unable to connect through sync_gateway to remote server

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to start sync_gateway from cmd with following command:

```
sync_gateway -url http://75.76.221.21:8091
```

I received following error:

> 20:33:23.014229 WARNING: Error installing Couchbase design doc: Put
>   http://192.168.2.102:8092/sync_gateway/_design/sync_gateway: dial tcp
>   192.168.2.102:8092: ConnectEx tcp: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
>   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond. -- db.installViews() at database.go:29120:33:44.055739
>
> WARNING: Error installing Couchbase design doc: Put
>   http:/_design/sync_housekeeping: dial tcp 192.168.2.102:8092:
>   ConnectExtcp: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
>   did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. --
>   db.installViews() at database.go:30520:33:44.055739
>
> FATAL: Error opening database: Put
>   192.168.2.102:8092/omnibazaar/_design/sync_housekeeping: dial tcp 192.168.2.102:8092: ConnectEx tcp: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
>   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond. -- rest.RunServer() at config.go:415

Comment: This question looks familiar.  Did you also ask this on our forums?

Answer (score 1):

How did you name your nodes in your Couchbase instance?  If you look at the Server Nodes tab, is one of your nodes named "192.168.2.102".  I see that from your sync gateway machine, you are trying to reach the Couchbase cluster using the 75.76.221.21 address.  Have you checked network connectivity, from your sync gateway machine, try "telnet 192.168.2.102 8092" and see if it connects.

One other thing, it is more common to start sync gateway by redirecting in a configuration file, you can find them in the examples directory.  For instance "sync_gateway < examples/config-server.json"